# Creating facebook application in rails 3 with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, facebook-canvas

I m new to heroku. I deployed my rails 3 application in heroku and it is running successfully. My need is to integrate this application to a facebook canvas application. My doubt is whether i need to create a new app with cloud hosting services in facebook or i can use my existing heroku app? If so, how can i make use of existing heroku app in facebook.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your Heroku Rails app running in a Facebook canvas:

1. Go to your Facebook application's settings page: `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app_id>/summary`
2. Enter your Heroku app's URL into both the **Canvas URL** and **Secure Canvas URL** fields

Note: Facebook requires SSL (https) for all canvas apps. If you don't have a certificate, just add the free **Piggyback SSL** plugin on your Heroku app: http://addons.heroku.com/ssl

Comment: This is slightly outdated as the Cedar stack (default for new Heroku apps) does away with the Piggyback SSL add-on. All cedar apps get SSL out of the box at their app-name.herokuapp.com address - which is usually fine for Facebook apps as the domain name is never shown. If you do want a full domain cert (for a hybrid FB app) the Expedited SSL add-on is the quickest way: https://addons.heroku.com/expeditedssl

Answer (score 1):

Go to your app settings and enter in the URL to your website into the canvas app settings section.